# How to redirect back to the start page on a button click with jquery in an MVC project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a button that directs a user to a view called Report, and on that Report view I have a cancel button and when I click it I need it to take me back to the very first page, which is Home/Index. When I click on the button it does take me back to Home/Index, but when I click the button to go back to the report view I get an error about the Resource cannot be found, when I look at the address bar I have /Home/FileAReport/Report, which is not right, on the file a report button click event it suppose to go to FileAReport/Report.
The code that takes me back to the Home/Index view is

```
$('#CancelFAR').on('click', function () {
    window.location.href = '/Home/Index/'
});
```

Now when I click that cancel button and then click on the FileAReport button, why is the address now Home/FileAReport/Report? and how can I fix this?

Comment: which version of mvc is this?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane, 5

Comment: and also is there a reason you need to use a button with js and not just a link? is the button intended to do anything more?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane, actually its a div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same confusion when I was new to MVC. It all depends on what is taken as the current url. Razor has several ways to generate the exact path based on the current page. One of the ways of generating a link is as follows:

```
@Html.Action("Action", "Controller")
```

In your case it would be something like

```
@Html.Action("Report", "FileAReport")
```

This function generates a html link or an `<a>` tag. You can check the overloads for more functionality. This way is however not recomended since it hides the html code in your code. You can instead use `@Url.Action` or `@Url.Content` to do the same. If you use `@Url.Action`, you can mention the action and controller like the example above. `@Url.Content` helps you generate any url from the root like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/FileAReport/Report")" >My link</a>
```

This clearly shows anyone that it is a link/anchortag. I am not sure why you are using a div instead of a link tag, but if it is because of the look, you can always use css to make it look as you like. However for any reason if you do need the actual url in javascript, you can declare something like the following in your razor file:

```
<script>
    var reportUrl = "@Url.Content("~/FileAReport/Report")";
</script>
```

And then you can use the `reportUrl` variable in your js file. So as you can see the `Url.Content` function can be used anywhere within razor.